# Does it makes sense to take vector<string_view> as a parameter

Tags: c++, string, vector, parameter-passing, string-view

I want a function that takes as input a vector of strings that I don't want to modify. So I thought about taking as input a `vector<string_view>`. However, if I do this, I can't pass a `vector<string>` as a parameter anymore.

Example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

void takesStringViewVectorRef(vector<string_view> const & v) {}

int main ()
{
  string_view strview; string str;
  takesStringViewVectorRef({"a", "b", strview, str}); // works, cool!

  vector<string> vec;
  takesStringViewVectorRef(vec); // doesn't work

  vector<const char *> vec2;
  takesStringViewVectorRef(vec2); // doesn't work either

  return 0;
}
```

Is this just a bad idea? Should I stick with `vector<string>`? I'm a little confused about this

Comment: If you're taking by a const reference then there's no performance benefit to using `string_view` and as you've found you'd have to make a new vector to hold the `string_view`s

Comment: @AlanBirtles but if I take a `vector<string>` the cool line does not work anymore :-(

Comment: `inline auto to_view(vector<string> const& v) -> vector<string_view> { return vector<string_view>(v.begin(), v.end()); }` and then call it `takesStringViewVectorRef(to_view(vec));`

Comment: Depending on what you want to do making your function take a pair of templated iterators is likely a good solution

Comment: Use `std::span<const T>` instead of `std::vector<T> const&`. It enables your function to accept `std::array` instances too. Otherwise you're gonna need a `std::ranges::view auto` with a `requires same_as<std::ranges::range_common_reference_t<T>, T const>` for the most generic case.

Comment: @Red.Wave It should be `std::ranges::[??_]range`, not a `view`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `range` can cover by-value ranges too. Regarding the OP, we need by-reference ranges aka `view`s.

Comment: @Red.Wave `view` only accepts range adapters like those in `std::views`, it wouldn't accept most containers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's exactly my point. Containers are *values*; copying them deep copies the elements. `view`s OTH are *references*; copying them just shallow copies some pointers, not the elements. The OP looks to need reference semantics and IMO, the proper form is top-level reference; a reference to container, rather than a container with references to elements.

Comment: @Red.Wave How would you pass containers to it? By wrapping them in `std::views::all`? Why do this, when you can accept (types satisfying) `std::ranges::range` by reference?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't like references on containers; they must be universal references in generic contexts. Moreover constraining to `ranges::view` prevents unintended copy. Explicitly applying `views::all` or `ranges::ref_view` on the range also clarifies the intent and improves readability.

Comment: @Red.Wave I see. That's an interesting take.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Considering your previous suggestion, a veiw captured by reference may exhibit 2 indirections to access the `begin` iterator. Capturing the `view` by value removes this 
minimal overhead too.  Not a big deal or performance critical an issue, but I guess I have some sort of OCD.

Comment: @Red.Wave Since all this is templated, I think the possible overhead of a reference could be removed by inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a template function that can work on the string type you put in like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

// using namespace std; <-- no don't do this
// some C++17 style type checking helpers

template<typename type_t>
constexpr bool is_stringlike_v = std::is_convertible_v<type_t, std::string_view>;

template<typename type_t>
using requires_stringlike_t = typename std::enable_if_t<is_stringlike_v<type_t>, void>;

// template function that accepts any stringlike type
template<typename type_t>
auto do_something_with_strings(const std::vector<type_t>& strings) -> requires_stringlike_t<type_t>
{
    for (const auto& string : strings)
    {
        std::cout << string << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string_view strview{ "strview" };
    std::string str{ "str" };

    // need to explicitly specialize since not all values in the "vector" are of the same type
    do_something_with_strings<std::string_view>({ "a", "b", strview, str }); // works, cool!

    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "std::string1", "std::string2" };
    do_something_with_strings(vec);

    std::vector<const char*> vec2{ "hello", "world" };
    do_something_with_strings(vec2);

    std::vector<int> vec3{1,2,3};
    //do_something_with_strings(vec3); <== will correctly not compile

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But `stringlike` should be a concept. Then you could write `template <stringlike T> void do_smth(std::vector<T> const&)`. And you would get better error messages (probably).

Comment: @bitmask I agree, I still make most of my examples using C++17 (more commonly in use). But I definitely would use concepts in C++20 and later

Comment: And also what @AlanBirtles said having iterators to stringlike types makes the function usable for other containers as well.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will continue using global std namespace for examples though :-)

Comment: Not using `using namespace std;` is a habit... just do it and it will become automatic. It is not that much typing ... at least the C++ committee chose a short namespace name ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's no single best answer.

But one thing is for sure, you should pass `std::span<const T>` instead of `const std::vector<T> &`, this way your function will also work with arrays and other contiguous containers.

If you expect this function to be widely used, then `std::span<const std::string_view>` sounds like a more versatile option (I assume nothing inside the function needs an actual `const std::string &`).

You could add a second overload accepting `std::span<const std::string>`, and forwarding to the `string_view` overload internally.

But if you expect this function to be called only in a few times, and callers use `std::vector<std::string>`, then there's no harm in accepting `std::span<const std::string>`.

---

As for templating the function... If this is a pure string manipulation algorithm, sure. If not, I wouldn't do it just to get a nicer call syntax. Templating everything is a road to slower build times.

Comment: If I could use C++20 I would surely use span! Thanks

Comment: @poipoi Pre-C++20 alternative to `span` is passing `const T *ptr, std::size_t size`. It should be faster too, if I remember correctly.